# Rest API callout using basic authorisation

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, http, salesfoce

```
String filter = 'OrderNumber eq \'1000035\' and SoldtoCustomer eq \'10045005\'';
    String Username = user;
    String Password = pass;
    String expand = 'EvLineDetailsSet';
    String format ='json';
    String reqBody ='$filter=' +filter;
    reqBody = reqBody + '&$expand=' + expand;               
    reqBody = reqBody + '&$format=' + format;  
    system.debug('********request Body*******'+reqBody);
    try{
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String endpoint =  'https://onehdwebpre.hunterdouglas.com/CUSTOMERORDERDETAILS/EvHeaderDetailsSet';
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');

        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(Username + ':' + Password);

        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setBody(reqBody);


        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('*******response*******' +response.getBody());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        system.debug('Inside catch'+e.getMessage());
    }
```

> 

I am using the above code but in response getting csrf token not valid while the URL is working on postman. Can anyone tell what is wrong in the code?

Comment: I would suggest to remove your username and password from the post.

Comment: What error code you are getting in response?